# SQL Server 2014 LAG Function Running Start and End Balances

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hoping someone out there can assist with a query I am attempting to write.  I am trying to write a running total / beginning and ending balance query using the LAG function in SQL 2014.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get the syntax correct and I'm wondering if this is possible.  Basically, the ending balance (endbal) value of the previous row needs to be the beginning balance (begbal) of the next row and so on.  Ending balance is computed as (beginning balance - principalcashflow)  Below is my sample query and table variable setup:

```
declare @calccashflow table(
    recordid int,
    cashflowdate date,
    begbal float,
    endbal float,
    principalcashflow float,
    interestcashflow float
);

/*populate with test data */
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,begbal,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(1,'2016-09-01',100000000.00,100000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(2,'2016-10-01',200000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(3,'2016-11-01',300000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(4,'2016-12-01',300000.0,200.0);

/*set the ending balance of the first row to begbal-principalcashflow*/
update @calccashflow set endbal=begbal -principalcashflow where recordid=1;
SELECT  recordid, 
        cashflowdate ,
        begbal=case when recordid=1 then begbal 
                else lag(endbal,1,0) over (order by recordid) end,
        endbal=(case when recordid=1 then endbal 
                 else (case when recordid=1 then begbal 
                            else lag(endbal,1,0) over (order by recordid)    end) - principalcashflow end),
        principalcashflow,
        interestcashflow     
FROM @calccashflow
```

The results are not quite what I'm looking for and after the 2nd row it all breaks down (see picture below):
[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQMR.png)

What I would like to see is as follows:

```
rowid  cashflowdate     begbal   endbal   principalcashflow
-----  ------------     ------   ------   -----------------
    1  2016-09-01     100000000 99900000              10000
    2  2016-10-01      99900000 99700000              20000
    3  2016-11-01      99700000 99400000              30000
    4  2016-12-01      99400000 99100000              30000
```

Here, the ending balance of the previous record becomes the beginning balance of the next record.  The ending balance for each row is calculated as (begbal-principalcashflow) as mentioned above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and desired results (in the form of a table) would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: Please see additional example provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using a cumulative sum, and the `first_value` window function. Notice that you don't even need to update the `endbal` column for the first record.  I took out the update.

```
declare @calccashflow table(
    recordid int,
    cashflowdate date,
    begbal float,
    endbal float,
    principalcashflow float,
    interestcashflow float
);

/*populate with test data */
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,begbal,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(1,'2016-09-01',100000000.00,100000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(2,'2016-10-01',200000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(3,'2016-11-01',300000.0,200.0);
insert into @calccashflow(recordid,cashflowdate,principalcashflow,interestcashflow)
values(4,'2016-12-01',300000.0,200.0);

with cte as (
  select recordid,
         cashflowdate,
         begbal,
         endbal = first_value(begbal) over (order by recordid) 
                  - sum(principalcashflow) over (order by recordid),
         principalcashflow,
         interestcashflow
  from @calccashflow
)
select recordid,
       cashflowdate,
       begbal = coalesce(begbal, endbal + principalcashflow),
       endbal,
       principalcashflow,
       interestcashflow
  from cte
 order by recordid;
```